# why can not I show a listview from the Asynctask?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a main activity which should call an Asynctask to bring a Json data from a remote URL after I get this data I parse them and put them to  listview as following :

Top20Activity.java

```
package com.example.example;

import com.example.example.neededClasses.FetchTop20FromDB;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Top20Activity extends FragmentActivity {

    //private TextView role;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top20);

        //role = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        new FetchTop20FromDB(this).execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top20, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

FetchTop20FromDB.java

```
package com.example.example.neededClasses;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.example.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FetchTop20FromDB extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    //private TextView roleField;
    private Context context;
    private ListView top20FinalMenu ;

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  
    ArrayList<String> top20listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    public FetchTop20FromDB(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
          //this.roleField = roleField;
       }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try{
            String link = "http://example.com/android_data.php";
            //URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
           (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

         //  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
           String line="";
           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
               JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
               for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    top20listItems.add(jo.getString("localteam_name"));
                }
               //sb.append(line);
              break;
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        // return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }
        return top20listItems;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the menu list.  
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.top20_menu_item, result);  

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_top20, null,true);

        // Find the ListView resource.     
        top20FinalMenu = (ListView) v.findViewById( R.id.top20Menu );


        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        top20FinalMenu.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 

    }
}
```

Activity_top20.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/top20Menu">  
    </ListView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Top20_menu_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/top20_teams"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:padding="10dp"  
     android:textSize="16sp" />  

    </LinearLayout>
```

The list is never shows I am sure that the data has been bought but why it is not showed I do not have any clue I hope to have some help on this?

Comment: Put `top20FinalMenu = (ListView) v.findViewById( R.id.top20Menu );` into Top20Activity.onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in you `onPostExecute()` method:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_top20, null,true);
```

You’re creating a *new* instance of a `View` that contains the ListView you’re populating. However, that is not the View that is shown by the `Top20Activity`.

You have to access and populate the original `ListView` that is shown by your `Activity` in order to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Asyntask` runs on seperate thread,you cannot access UI and UI elements from there.But you can use `onPreExecute, onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate` methods of `Asyntask` because they run on the UI thread. if you want to find listview in asyntask then use `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`.

change `onPostExecute` to

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the menu list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.top20_menu_item, result);  
     LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);  //set false here ...you se it to true

    // Find the ListView resource.     
    top20FinalMenu = (ListView) root.findViewById( R.id.top20Menu );


    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    top20FinalMenu.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 

}
```

Comment: As you can see I use the onPostExecute but still not showing my List in the activity did I miss anything because I am new to android ??

Comment: I change it but it gives me the following error :
`findViewById is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: have u used capital C?, if yes change it to small c

Comment: try setting false here  ...View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

Comment: it is giving the same error but this time `inflate is undefined` even I change it to false

Comment: inflator is objectof layout inflator

Comment: I am sorry but if u check my `onPostExecutor` u will find it the same as your answer after editing

Comment: i mentioned in comment that you set it to true. change that to false.

Comment: yes I saw ur comment and change it but it is not solving the problem . still not showing the list in the activity

Answer (score 0):

You can assess any UI element form the asyncTask. But you have to call them in the right function.

UI can be updated in the `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I use the `onPostExecute()` but how can I update the UI inside it ? Is there any thing I should call it?

Comment: As long as you have the context of the current activity, you can update your UI...

Answer (score 0):

It's my consider, may be help you.

You use the ArrayAdapter class, it is android system class so you need

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

layout for the same now you use

```
R.layout.top20_menu_item
```

like,

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,yourarraylist)
```

**OR**

if you want use this file

```
R.layout.top20_menu_item
```

so please create your own custom ArrayAdapter.